# circuit schematic symbol for buffer with control input

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

`circuitikz` has an `op amp` component type with two inputs, output, and `up` and `down` ports, usually used for power supply rails.  There's also a `buffer` component type (which I think is provided by `tikz` itself, not the `circuitikz` library) which has one input and one output and no vertical ports.

I'm looking for a buffer/amp with one input, one output, and the vertical ports, for use as control pins.  My use case is a track-and-hold (aka sample-and-hold) amplifier symbol, but a tri-state buffers are also very common and require a control input.

[image: circuit exemplifying SHA]

Ok, that figure uses a two-input SHA.  But I'm sure you can imagine what the one-input version should look like (basically, I'm trying to make a single symbol that hides all that complexity, for a high-level block diagram).

[image: tristate buffer symbols]

Does `tikz` or one of its extension libraries provide such a beast?  If not, how can I properly align a vertical wire with the edge of the buffer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring new node shapes is a bit of a pain, but you get used to it. Here are two new circuit shapes `tri state buffer active low` and `tri state buffer active high` that behave like `buffer gate` and `not gate`, but offer a new anchor `control`. This allows you to draw this:

[image]

using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, on grid]
\node (i) {x};
\node (buf) [right of=i, tri state buffer active high] {};
\node (ctrl) [above=of buf] {c};
\node (o) [right of=buf] {y};

\draw (i) -- (buf.input)
    (ctrl) -- (buf.control)
    (buf.output) -- (o);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, on grid]
\node (i) {x};
\node (buf) [right of=i, tri state buffer active low] {};
\node (ctrl) [above=1 of buf] {c};
\node (o) [right of=buf] {y};

\draw (i) -- (buf.input)
    (ctrl) -- (buf.control)
    (buf.output) -- (o);
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, circuits.logic.US}

\makeatletter%
%
%
\pgfdeclareshape{tri state buffer active high}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=buffer gate US]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=buffer gate US]
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north east} 
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{input}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{output}
    \anchor{control}{%
        \dimensions
        \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\csname pgf@anchor@buffer gate US@north west\endcsname}{\tipanchor}{\centerpoint}{\centerpoint\advance\pgf@y1pt}%
    }%
    \backgroundpath{%
        \dimensions%
        \pgf@xc\halfwidth%
        \pgf@yc\halfheight%
        \advance\pgf@xc-\outerxsep%
        \advance\pgf@yc-\outerysep%
        {%
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\tipanchor}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.833333\pgf@xc}{1.166666\pgf@yc}}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.833333\pgf@xc}{-1.166666\pgf@yc}}%
            \pgfpathclose%
            %
            % Draw the input.
            %
            \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\pgf@lib@sh@itext\csname input-1\endcsname%
                {%
                    \pgfpathcircle{%
                        \pgf@xa\halfside%
                        \pgf@x-.833333\pgf@xa%
                        \advance\pgf@x-.5\pgflinewidth%
                        \advance\pgf@x-\invertedradius%
                        \pgf@y0pt%
                    }{+\invertedradius}%                
                }%
            \fi%                
        }%
    }%
}

\pgfdeclareshape{tri state buffer active low}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=buffer gate US]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=buffer gate US]
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{mid east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{north east} 
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{input}
    \inheritanchor[from=buffer gate US]{output}
    \anchor{control}{%
        \dimensions
        \tipanchor%
        \pgf@xa\pgf@x%  
        \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
        \csname pgf@anchor@buffer gate US@north west\endcsname%
        \advance\pgf@xa-\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@ya-\pgf@y%
        \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\csname pgf@anchor@buffer gate US@north west\endcsname}{\tipanchor}{\centerpoint}{\centerpoint\advance\pgf@y2pt}%
        \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\pgf@xa^2+\pgf@ya^2)/\pgf@xa*\invertedradius}
        \advance\pgf@y\pgfmathresult pt
        \advance\pgf@y\invertedradius
    }%
    \backgroundpath{%
        \dimensions%
        \pgf@xc\halfwidth%
        \pgf@yc\halfheight%
        \advance\pgf@xc-\outerxsep%
        \advance\pgf@yc-\outerysep%
        {%
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\tipanchor}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.833333\pgf@xc}{1.166666\pgf@yc}}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.833333\pgf@xc}{-1.166666\pgf@yc}}%
            \pgfpathclose%
            %
            % Draw the input.
            %
            \pgfpathcircle{%
                \tipanchor%
                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%  
                \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
                \csname pgf@anchor@buffer gate US@north west\endcsname%
                \advance\pgf@xa-\pgf@x%
                \advance\pgf@ya-\pgf@y%
                \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\csname pgf@anchor@buffer gate US@north west\endcsname}{\tipanchor}{\centerpoint}{\centerpoint\advance\pgf@y1pt}%
                \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\pgf@xa^2+\pgf@ya^2)/\pgf@xa*\invertedradius}
        \advance\pgf@y\pgfmathresult pt
                }{+\invertedradius}%
            \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\pgf@lib@sh@itext\csname input-1\endcsname%
                {%
                    \pgfpathcircle{%
                        \pgf@xa\halfside%
                        \pgf@x-.833333\pgf@xa%
                        \advance\pgf@x-.5\pgflinewidth%
                        \advance\pgf@x-\invertedradius%
                        \pgf@y0pt%
                    }{+\invertedradius}%                
                }%
            \fi%                
        }%
    }%
}

\tikzset{
    circuit declare symbol=tri state buffer active low,
    set tri state buffer active low graphic={draw, shape=tri state buffer active low, minimum size=5mm},
    circuit declare symbol=tri state buffer active high,
    set tri state buffer active high graphic={draw,shape=tri state buffer active high,minimum size=5mm}
}

\begin{document}

%
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, on grid]
\node (i) {x};
\node (buf) [right of=i, tri state buffer active high] {};
\node (ctrl) [above=of buf] {c};
\node (o) [right of=buf] {y};

\draw (i) -- (buf.input)
    (ctrl) -- (buf.control)
    (buf.output) -- (o);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, on grid]
\node (i) {x};
\node (buf) [right of=i, tri state buffer active low] {};
\node (ctrl) [above=1 of buf] {c};
\node (o) [right of=buf] {y};

\draw (i) -- (buf.input)
    (ctrl) -- (buf.control)
    (buf.output) -- (o);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's amazing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does this answer your question, or are there any points left uncovered?

Comment: I found it very useful.  I wanted to wait a bit to see if someone would recommend a library that already contained it, but no one has so I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution if you'll only be using active high tri-state buffers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (E) at (0,0.5) {$E$};
\node (Y) at (2,0) {$Y$};
\node[buffer gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=n] at (1,0) (TS) {};
\draw (A) -- (TS.input);
\draw (E) -| (TS.north);
\draw (TS.output) -- (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]